# how to manage a directive from your controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

I am looking for a angular pattern to achieves what the ionic library does with its *delegate* pattern.

Take the [slide box component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/), for example:

When you use its directive (`<ion-slide-box>`) in your view you can automatically inject in your controller some sort of service ([`$ionicSlideBoxDelegate`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)) associated to the directive object, that you can use to control it with methods like:

```
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.start()    // Start sliding again if the slideBox was stopped
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.stop()     // Stop sliding
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next()     // Go to the next slide.
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous() // Go to the previous slide
//...
```

### My best attempt:

1. create a directive with an isolated scope that receives only one parameter (the delegate service object)
2. in the controller instantiate a new instance of this Delegate service and attach it to the `$scope`
3. in the view pass the instance to the Delegate service to the directive

Here is some code to illustrate my solution. In this example I am trying to create a *fake progress bar* directive that will act like a normal progress bar but it will advance automatically, unless we tell it to `stop`. And it will never reach 100% unless told to do so by calling to `complete`.

#### The directive and its attached Handler (or delegate):

```
angular.module("fakeProgressbar", [])
.directive 'fakeProgressbar', ->
  scope:
    handler: '='
  restrict: 'E'
  replace: false
  template: '
      <progressbar class="progress-striped active" max="handler.config.max" type="{{handler.config.type}}" value="handler.config.value">
        {{ handler.config.value }} %
      </progressbar>
      '
.factory 'FakeProgressbarHandler', ($interval, $timeout, $q) ->
  class FakeProgressbar
    start: -> # ...
    success: -> # ...
    complete: -> # ...
    stop: -> # ...
```

#### In your controller:

```
angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap", "fakeProgressbar"])
.controller "fakeProgressbarExampleController", ($scope, FakeProgressbarHandler) ->
  $scope.fakeProgressbarHandler = new FakeProgressbarHandler()
  $scope.fakeProgressbarHandler.start() # start animation inmediately

  # now you can do `$scope.fakeProgressbarHandler.stop()` or `$scope.fakeProgressbarHandler.complete()`
```

#### In your view:

```
<fake-progressbar handler="fakeProgressbarHandler"></fake-progressbar>
```

A complete example of this working code can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ehsuu1nKxeu2W7ktTVFC?p=preview

### The question:

The question is, of course, how to get rid of having to attach the `fakeProgressbarHandler` to the scope to later pass it back to the directive.

The *ionic delegate pattern* seems to achieve this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't too much magic with the ionic delegates. Whenever the directive is used, the controller registers an instance with a delegateService. For example in slideBox:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/slideBox.js#L127

```
var deregisterInstance = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate._registerInstance(
  slider, $attrs.delegateHandle, function() {
    return $ionicHistory.isActiveScope($scope);
  }
);
```

The delegate code is mostly found here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/utils/delegateService.js

```
  DelegateService.prototype._registerInstance = function(instance, handle, filterFn) {
    var instances = this._instances;
    instance.$$delegateHandle = handle;
    instance.$$filterFn = filterFn || trueFn;
    instances.push(instance);

    return function deregister() {
      var index = instances.indexOf(instance);
      if (index !== -1) {
        instances.splice(index, 1);
      }
    };
  };
```

---

Here is a simplified example of the registering (untested):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstController', function($scope, DelegateService) {
  $scope.start = function(handle) {
    DelegateService.getInstance(handle).start();
  };
  $scope.stop = function(handle) {
    DelegateService.getInstance(handle).stop();
  };
});

app.controller('secondController', function($scope, DelegateService) {
  $scope.startAll = function() {
    Object.keys(DelegateService._instances).forEach(function(handle) {
      DelegateService._instances[handle].start();
    });
  };
  $scope.stopAll = function(handle) {
    Object.keys(DelegateService._instances).forEach(function(handle) {
      DelegateService._instances[handle].stop();
    });
  };
});

app.directive('someDirective', function(SomeDirectiveDelegate, DelegateService) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.progress = {
        amount: 0
      };
      var delegate = new SomeDirectiveDelegate($scope.progress);
      DelegateService._registerInstance(delegate, $attrs.handle);
    },
    template: '<div>{{ progress.amount }}</div>'
  };
});

app.factory('SomeDirectiveDelegate', function($interval) {
  function SomeDirectiveDelegate(progress) {
    var interv;

    function stop() {
      if (interv) {
        $interval.cancel(interv);
        interv = null;
      }
    }

    function start() {
      stop();
      interv = $interval(function() {
        progress.amount += 1;
      }, 100);
    }

    return {
      start: start,
      stop: stop,
    };
  }
  return SomeDirectiveDelegate;
});

app.service('DelegateService', function() {
  this._instances = {};
  this._registerInstance = function(instance, handle) {
    this._instances[handle] = instance;
  };
  this.getInstance = function(handle) {
    return this._instances[handle];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='firstController'>
    <some-directive handle="1"></some-directive>
    <button ng-click="start(1)">start1</button>
    <button ng-click="stop(1)">stop1</button>
    <some-directive handle="2"></some-directive>
    <button ng-click="start(2)">start2</button>
    <button ng-click="stop(2)">stop2</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller='secondController'>
    <button ng-click="startAll()">start all</button>
    <button ng-click="stopAll()">stop all</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was reading that code this weekend but struggled to make some sense out of it. Your comment replies my original question and helps me undestand it :)

I have one more question though. In ionic when you inject the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` if find automatically the one that is being used in your scope. I'm not sure, but I suspect that this is done via the `$$filterFn` that in the example of `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` is checking wether the current scope is active or note.

Does vanilla angular offer a similar feature to `$ionicHistory`'s `isActiveScope` method?

Thanks again :D